# Text's color doesn't change when switching to light theme

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When I cwitch to Light theme text's color doesn't change but divider's color and other element's colors changed. All other colors change correcly

[Light theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RE5z.jpg)

[Darktheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ONNR.jpg)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjlDA.png)

**Theme.kt**
`

```
private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
primary = Purple500,
//    primaryVariant = Purple700,
//    secondary = Sky,
//    secondaryVariant = Sky,
    background = Black,
//    surface = Black,
//    error = Black,
    onPrimary = White2,
//    onSecondary = Black,
    onBackground = White2,
//    onSurface = Black,
//    onError = Black
)
private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    primary = Purple500,
//    primaryVariant = Purple700,
//    secondary = Sky,
//    secondaryVariant = Sky,
    background = White2,
//    surface = Black,
//    error = Black,
    onPrimary = Black,
//    onSecondary = Black,
    onBackground = Black,
//    onSurface = Black,
//    onError = Black
)

val redLightPalette = LightColorPalette.copy(
    primary = Red,
    onPrimary = White,
)
val redDarkPalette = DarkColorPalette.copy(
    primary = Red,
    onPrimary = White,
)

val orangeLightPalette = LightColorPalette.copy(
    primary = Orange,
    onPrimary = White,
)
val orangeDarkPalette = DarkColorPalette.copy(
    primary = Orange,
    onPrimary = White,
)

val yellowLightPalette = LightColorPalette.copy(
    primary = Yellow,
    onPrimary = Black,
)
val yellowDarkPalette = DarkColorPalette.copy(
    primary = Yellow,
    onPrimary = Black,
)

val greenLightPalette = LightColorPalette.copy(
    primary = Green,
    onPrimary = White,
)
val greenDarkPalette = DarkColorPalette.copy(
    primary = Green,
    onPrimary = White,
)

val skyLightPalette = LightColorPalette.copy(
    primary = Sky,
    onPrimary = White,
)
val skyDarkPalette = DarkColorPalette.copy(
    primary = Sky,
    onPrimary = White,
)

@Composable
fun LifeControllerTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    primary: Color = Purple700,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        when(primary) {
            Purple500 -> DarkColorPalette
            Red -> redDarkPalette
            Orange -> orangeDarkPalette
            Yellow -> yellowDarkPalette
            Green -> greenDarkPalette
            Sky -> skyDarkPalette
            else -> DarkColorPalette
        }

    } else {
        when(primary){
            Purple500 -> LightColorPalette
            Red -> redLightPalette
            Orange -> orangeLightPalette
            Yellow -> yellowLightPalette
            Green -> greenLightPalette
            Sky -> skyLightPalette
            else -> LightColorPalette
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

`

**Type.kt**
`

```
val typography = Typography(
        h1 = TextStyle(
//            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal,
            fontSize = 22.sp
        ),
        h2 = TextStyle(
//            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
            fontSize = 22.sp
        ),
        h3 = TextStyle(
//            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal,
            fontSize = 20.sp
        ),
        h4 = TextStyle(
//            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
            fontSize = 20.sp
        ),
        h5 = TextStyle(
//            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal,
            fontSize = 18.sp
        ),
        h6 = TextStyle(
//            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
            fontSize = 18.sp
        ),
        body1 = TextStyle(
//            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
            fontSize = 16.sp
        ),
        body2 = TextStyle(
//            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
            fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
            fontSize = 14.sp
        ),
    )
```

`

I tried setting the text color like a `remember { mutableStateOf(Color) }` , removing all white from the palette but that didn't work.
It looks like the Text doesn't understand that the Theme has changed...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add the Code of your Theme.kt file and try adding it as code not as a picture

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is that you are defining your text color in the style parameter. In a Text composable you can define your text color in the color parameter. Try removing the style argument and adding the color argument:

```
Text(
    text = "Some Text",
    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
)
```

In your code clip, I see you have `MaterialTheme.colors.onBackround`, for me 'colors' is 'colorScheme' by default, so I've used that, but if 'colors' is what works in your app, just substitute it in.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work too.  It is also very important for me that this particular style is applied.
* In this case `colorScheme == colors`

Comment: I tried replicating this in one of my projects, but couldn't. I'm not sure this is a Text issue. Could you share the function this is in, as well as your Theme.kt and Type.kt files? Not sure if it might be an issue there, but more information would be helpful.